# Null Object Reference

Tags: c#, nunit, null, testing

Using Nunit to test C# code with the following code block:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    thisReport.Id = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("id").Value;
    thisReport.Name = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name").Value;
    thisReport.Desc = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("desc").Value;
    if (node.SelectNodes("subreport").Count > 0)
    {
        thisReport.HasSubReport = true;
        subReportNodeList = node.SelectNodes("subreport");
        foreach(XmlNode subNode in subReportNodeList)
        {
            mySubReport.ParentID = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("id").Value;
            mySubReport.Priority = subNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("priority").Value;
            mySubReport.SubReportId = subNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("id").Value;
            mySubReport.SubReportName = subNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name").Value;
            string sTime = subNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("time").Value;
            mySubReport.Time = Convert.ToInt16(sTime);
            thisReport.SubReportsList.Add(mySubReport);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        thisReport.HasSubReport = false;
    }
    reports.Add(thisReport);
}
```

The code fails with a null object reference on the line:

```
            thisReport.SubreportsList.Add(mySubReport)
```

But looking at the locals, `thisReport` exists and has the values assigned at the top of the block, and `mySubReport` exists and has the values assigned just above the line where it's added to thisReport. All the values in `mySubReport` are valid and `SubReportsList` in `thisReport` is a generic list of type `SubReport`.

So, where's the null? It seems so simple, it must be something really obvious that I can't see.

Comment: If the exception occurs in `thisReport.SubReportsList.Add(mySubReport);` and `thisReport` and `mySubReport` are not null, then the only option is that  `thisReport.SubReportsList` is null. Double-check your property implementation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 5):

You've not instantiated SubReportsList before calling `Add`. Do the following before adding `mySubReport`:

```
thisReport.SubReportsList = new List<SubReport>();
thisReport.SubReportsList.Add(mySubReport);
```

You could also change your SubReportsList property to make your life easier:

```
public class Report
{
    public IList<SubReport> SubReportsList
    {
        get
        {
            if (_subReportsList == null)
            {
                _subReportsList = new List<SubReport>();
            }
            return _subReportsList;
        }
    }
    private IList<SubReport> _subReportsList;
}
```

Doing this would instantiate your List if it's called while it's null.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably first do:

```
thisReport.SubReportsList = new List<SubReport>();
```

Answer (score 1):

It must be `SubReportsList` that is null then.

Answer (score 1):

`thisReport.SubReportsList` is your null reference; you've declared it but not initialized it. You can initialize it (probably with a new instance) either in a constructor for `thisReport`'s type, or just before you start adding things to it.

Answer (score 1):

As @GenericTypeTea and @Dan Dumitru have already provided good answers I will just add that it is possible to "automatically" do this by adding an implicit construction if the value is null when you call the property. You can do this if you are not using auto-properties ala:

```
public class Report {
 // ... other code ...
 private List<SubReports> _subReports = null;

 public List<SubReport> SubReports {
    get {
      if (_subReports == null) { _subReports = new List<SubReports>(); }
      return _subReports;
    }
 }
}
```

There are some caveats to be noted, like making it thread-safe (this is off-the-cuff), but the basic implementation will work for you. I would be careful using this desing as it can cause the creation of objects you don't necessarily need just by checking properties. If that is undesirable then stick with the implementations recommended above.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to initialize the list by using the `new` keyword. Otherwise the list itself will be null.